# No rule to make target 'libglut.so', needed by 'main'. Stop

Tags: cmake

i'm experiencing this error with make.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(opengl C)

include_directories(headers)

add_executable(main main.c)

target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libglut.so)
```

this is my cmakelists, but when i run `make` i get this error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'path/to/libglut.so', needed by 'main'. Stop.
```

i'm really at a loss of what to do. please help.

Comment: This isn't a makefile question, since you're using cmake, so the `makefile` tag isn't really appropriate.  But, does the file `libglut.so` exist in the source directory, like your cmake file says it does?  It looks like, from the error message, it does not.  That's your problem.

Comment: @MadScientist yes. here's my file structure:```build  CMakeLists.txt  freeglut  libglut.so  main.c
```

Comment: If you run `file path/to/libglut.so` using the same path as the error from `make`, and in the same directory (make should print the directory it is running in), what does it say?  Is `libglut.so` an actual file, or is it a symlink?  If a symlink, does it point to a real file or is it "dangling"?  Just to clarify, the ONLY way you'll ever get that error from make is if the file it is complaining about doesn't exist.  If it exists, then make will not need to make it and you won't get that error.

Comment: @MadScientist i sorted it by removing ``${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}``